# FLASK, How to redirect Google autentication to a local html.file

Tags: flask, google-authentication

Hi everyone I have implemented the Google Authentication with API.
I would like that once the user is authenticated the page redirect to a local html/Javascript application.
I am trying the following code which is not working because it is not finding the correct url.

from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, session, request, render_template
from authlib.integrations.flask_client import OAuth
import os
from datetime import timedelta

```
# App config
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "random secret"

# oAuth Setup
oauth = OAuth(app)
google = oauth.register(
    name='google',
    client_id='',
    client_secret='',
    access_token_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    access_token_params=None,
    authorize_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
    authorize_params=None,
    api_base_url='https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/',
    client_kwargs={'scope': 'openid email profile'},
)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    email = dict(session).get('email',None)
    return f'Hello, {email}!'

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    google = oauth.create_client('google')
    redirect_uri = url_for('authorize', _external=True)
    return google.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri)


@app.route('/authorize')
def authorize():
    google = oauth.create_client('google')
    token = google.authorize_access_token()
    resp = google.get('userinfo')
    user_info = resp.json()
    session['email'] = user_info['email']
    return redirect('file:///home/luca/Desktop/ft_userdata/ProvaLogIn/prova.htm')





if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

THe html that i am trying to render is simply an html local file with wrote  hello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create folder called `templates` inside your project in this folder you will add your html file in your case it will be `prova.html`

and change the return statement to

```
    return render_template('prova.html')
```

this how should your directory tree should look like (general view)

```
├── app.py
├── static
└── templates
    └── status.html
```

hope this solve your issue